# Perform SSH Connection inside Airflow's python_callable?

Tags: ssh, airflow-scheduler, airflow

In an Airflow 1.10.10 DAG, we have a `ShortCircuitOperator` that uses the python function `check_remote_server()` to decide the branch.

In `check_remote_server_data()` function, how can we start an SSH connection to the remote server, run a bash command on it and get the results?

Is it possible to use the Airflow SSH Connection that I have previously defined using the Web UI?

```
def check_remote_server_data():
    pass   # how can we use a predefined Airflow SSH connection, named `remote`?

with dag:
    shortcircuitop = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id='shortcircuitop',
        python_callable=check_remote_server_data,
        dag=dag
    )
```

---

I am only able to do it using `SSHOperator`, but I need the results to be used to determine the short circuit conditions:

```
SSHOperator(
    task_id='sshop',
    ssh_conn_id='remote',
    command='date +%F',
dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SSHOperator` supports an argument, `do_xcom_push`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator.SSHOperator.execute) to pass the output of the command as an [XCom value](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) that you can access in your `ShortCircuitOperator`:

```py
def check_remote_server_data(**context):
    xcom_stdout = context["task_instance"].xcom_pull(task_ids="ssh_task_id")

with dag:
    ssh_operator = SSHOperator(task_id="ssh_task_id", do_xcom_push=True, ...)

    shortcircuitop = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id='shortcircuitop',
        python_callable=check_remote_server_data,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )

    ssh_operator >> shortcircuitop >> [other_task0, other_task1, ...]
```